# actualizo un archivo js en el servidor pero luego en la consola sigue apareciendo igual el archivo

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filezilla

Hola con el filezilla he actualizado un archivo javascript pero luego en la consola me aparece el mismo error y el archivo aparece igual. Estoy usando wordpress, pero no creo que sea ese el problema, he cerrado y vuelto a abrir el firefox y nada lo mismo.

he copiado el archivo del servidor a local y esta con los cambios en el código.

el error es TypeError: nombre.val is not a function[Saber más]

esta es la linea

```
if((document.getElementById("nombre").value.length < 4) || (correo.value.length < 4)|| (mensaje.value.length < 6))
```

pero en la consola me aparece

```
if((nombre.val().length < 4) || (correo.val().length < 4)|| (mensaje.val().length < 6))
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: Es probable que tengas un problema `cache`. Intenta borrar el cache del navegador o forzar la recarga usando `Ctrl + F5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es común tener cacheado en Mozilla FireFox o Google Chrome.
Podes solucionar el problema de dos maneras diferentes.

1. Forzando la recarga en el navegador web (Mozilla FireFoz o Google Chrome) usando Ctrl + F5. Muchas veces no funciona este método, entonces recurrí a al método 2.
2. Borrar el cache del navegador, borrando en tu historial. No hace falta que sea de todo el período, solo de las ultimas horas.
3. Otra forma es a entrar en modo privado o incógnito de tu navegador. Proba con Google Chrome y luego con el Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: ya he borrado la cache y sigo teniendo el problema.

Comment: @RafaelHernández agrega algo mas en la respuesta

Comment: ya he borrado bien la cache. solucionado